# How to set MX record so that delivery results in temporary failure

Tags: smtp, mx-record

I am moving an SMTP server from a host to another. In order to make things as simple as possible for me (and since I don't care if email are delayed a few hours), I would like to adopt this strategy:

1. I set the MX record for that domain to some value that ensures that each delivery attempt result in temporary failure, and wait for the TTL to expire. This way senders trying to deliver will just start holding their messages until I am done.
2. I copy mailboxes and relevant stuff from the old to the new host. I test that new host is working properly. Senders are expected to keep delayed messages for a few days, so I have plenty of time.
3. I update the MX record so that it points to the new host. As soon as senders will want to retry, they will succeed with the new host.

The difficult point is #1: how can I set MX record so that no actual delivery is attempted and the message is delayed? Setting no MX does not work, because then A or AAAA resolution is attempted, and I want to keep A and AAAA to the old host to avoid disrupting other services. Would setting it to a non existing domain do my trick? I could not understand if such an error is going to be interpreted as temporary or permanent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure this is a good strategy, and not something I would attempt at a DNS level if I can avoid it. To implement it though, just find an IP address you control, make sure it does not have anything listening on port 25 and point the MX record at an A record to that address.  If you have time on your hands, set a lower priority (higher number) and low TTL for this record. Set the TTL for your primary MX low as well.

You could use your old MX server and simply stop the SMTP service on it - that is likely the easiest way to achieve your goal, but is not a DNS level solution.

What you are looking for to achieve your remote queueing of email is a server which is not answering on port 25 or a server which returns an error (eg 421).

I might attempt it differently, either by setting up a server to accept email and queue it so I can flush it to a primary server when it is up again, or (if using maildir format) by using having new messages come into the server immediately and and sync the old onrs. Ideally you will want to shut down POP/IMAP during this time.

Answer (score 2):

Your method is a sure fire way of losing email. What you want to do is to stop/block/disable inbound SMTP at the current host. Sending servers will then queue the email and attempt delivery later (usually up to 48 hours).

When the new host is ready then change the MX record accordingly. Once email is flowing to the new host you can copy the mailbox contents from the old host to the new host.

Answer (score 0):

> 2. I copy mailboxes and relevant stuff from the old to the new host. I
>      test that new host is working properly. Senders are expected to keep
>      delayed messages for a few days, so I have plenty of time.

If I understand your intentions correctly, you want to allocate yourself some time to copy stuff and test. I would aim for near-zero downtime.

You can test the new host without actually changing the DNS. Just copy the new configuration over to the new host, then populate the mailboxes (they don't have to have all the mails, just enough for testing).

Then, from a test machine you can simply add an entry in your `hosts` file that points to the new IP address in order to bypass regular DNS resolution. Then start testing send & receive. When your configuration is fully ready, change the DNS to switch over to the new host, and you can decommission the old host immediately so that it will not receive any more mails.

One simple trick would be to block ports 25/465 etc at firewall level, for example using `iptables`.

To sum up I would do all testing *before* stopping mail service and changing DNS settings. There is always a chance that something goes wrong and you (and your client) will be under stress and racing against time.

There is one thing you have not mentioned: how you will be copying the mails from one host to another and what kind of volume are we talking about. For example if you will be using Imapsync, I think it should be possible to perform *incremental synchronization*, so that by the time you do the switch the new host will already have almost 100% of the mails.